# C# - invariant culture

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a double to a decimal with a dot instead of a comma. I feel like I have tried every single possible way (except a working one) so I'm out of ideas.

```
double amount = myUsd / price;
string amountAsString = amount.ToString();
decimal value = Decimal.Parse(amountAsString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This one gives a FormatException for example.

Thanks

Comment: When you use Culture.InvariantCulture in the Parse() call then you must also use it in the ToString() call.  I'd imagine you could post a better snippet that is more similar to your real code.

Comment: Convert your double directly: `decimal value = (decimal)amount;` then culture does not matter. Note: internally neither a dot nor a comma is used to store numbers. They are stored in a binary format. The dot/comma-thing only applies to strings containing numbers.

Comment: My problem is that I'm sending to an API that only takes a dot and casting it to decimal does not seem to work.

Comment: It sounds like your API takes a string of a specific format. Convert your double to a decimal as @Olivier... suggested, then convert the decimal to a string in whatever format you want (with ToSting and a format specified and a culture; actually, you may be able to skip the decimal conversion altogether)

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant said, if you Parse in the same way as you Format you'll avoid a lot of issues -> Use `string amountAsString = amount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

**EDIT**

Since you're passing in an exponential notation you need to tell the Parser this. This worked with your example value:

```
decimal value = Decimal.Parse(amountAsString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I suggest NOT formatting it as a Double. First convert it to a Decimal. Then parse it as a Decimal:

```
double amount = myUsd / price;
Decimal decAmount = (Decimal)amount;
string amountAsString = decAmount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
decimal value = Decimal.Parse(amountAsString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then it'll never get formatted in exponential notation.

Also see this [C# Fiddle snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OmlB44)

Comment: Ok, but how do I convert this back to a decimal? It's crashing here because of formatException  string amountAsString = price.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                decimal value = Decimal.Parse(amountAsString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Is it crashing on the Parse or the Format? (I'm assuming the Parse)

Comment: FormatException at StringToNumber, at ParseDecimal and at Decimal.Parse

Comment: "2,6955E-05", it's a very small number. It seems like no matter what I do it ends up with a comma. Here's some other things I found on SO that I tried and not a dot in sight. https://hastebin.com/vuqojodaza.cs (easier to read than in a comment)

Comment: I may have got it to work by setting this: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

Comment: I apologize for not responding, I haven't had the chance to test this yet because I ran into another problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344511/c-sharp-computer-specific-setting-causing-malformed-strings) that made it impossible to test.  I will do so as soon as possible.